# users who have received thanks, active record, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i created a small module of thanks, in this module, the current_user sends thanks to other users, is there a query where I can show only the amount of thanks that each user has? The main idea is to show a list with the thanks that each user has recieved and the number of these

controller/gratitudes_controller.rb:

```
 def index
    @gratitudes = Gratitude.all
    @gratitude_user = "query"

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @gratitudes }
    end
  end
```

this is the models

```
class Gratitude < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :send_to_user, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "send_to_user_id"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_may :gratitudes
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group`

`User.joins(:gratitudes).group(:id).size` and you will have something like

`{1=>1, 25=>1, 26=>1, 27=>1, 28=>5, 29=>1, 30=>1, 31=>1, 32=>1, 33=>1}`

The key is id of user and the value is number of gratitudes of user.

Answer (score 0):

I *believe* following is what you want in the models:

```rb
class Gratitude < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, inverse_of: :sent_gratitudes, foreign_key: "user_id", class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :recipient, inverse_of: :received_gratitudes, foreign_key: "send_to_user_id", class_name: "User"
end
```

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sent_gratitudes, inverse_of: :sender, foreign_key: "user_id", class_name: "Gratitude"
  has_many :received_gratitudes, inverse_of: :recipient, foreign_key: "send_to_user_id", class_name: "Gratitude"
end
```

You should be able to extract/query items accordingly after that.